# Accessing to names of the elements processed by the R *apply functions

Tags: r, apply, lapply

When using the R `*apply` functions, sometime one would like to access to the names of the processed elements inside the apply processing function. To make it clear, consider first this for-loop:

```
df=data.frame(x=1:3, y=11:13)
for(i in 1:ncol(df)){
    cat('processing col', names(df)[i], '\n')
    print(df[[i]])
}        

# processing col x  
# [1] 1 2 3         
# processing col y  
# [1] 11 12 13
```

When moving to the apply version:

```
lapply(df, function(col){
    ## processing col ??
    col})

# $x             
# [1] 1 2 3      
#                        
# $y             
# [1] 11 12 13
```

how to access the column names from inside the anonymous apply function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can't be done, except how you've done it with `for`.  If you want to return a structure with the results (and would be appending to a list, for example), `*apply` may still be appropriate.

```
x <- lapply(names(iris), function(name) {
        cat("processing col", name, "\n")
        iris[[name]]
     })
## processing col Sepal.Length 
## processing col Sepal.Width 
## processing col Petal.Length 
## processing col Petal.Width 
## processing col Species 

names(x) <- names(iris)
```

`x` is now a list containing the columns of the data frame `iris`.

Comment: Thanks Matthew, this at least confirmed my idea about not being able to access names when passing the list object (or the likes). The name-based solution is the one that I  use too. I wonder if it is still more efficient than the non-functional `for` approach and more efficient than the straight use of `*apply` (i.e. without the names trick, when names are not strictly necessary).

Comment: @antonio The `*apply` functions are only slightly faster than an application of `for`.  Use them when you want to iterate through a list and return structured output, such as another list.

Answer (score 0):

Two things to note here:
First: The for loop, doesn't have a return value, but the lapply does.
Second: The lapply does not pass the column name, only the unnamed vector.

So something like this a better generic solution:

```
x <- lapply(1:ncol(df),function(i){
  cat('processing col', names(df)[i], '\n')
  print(df[[i]])
  })
```

You can later discard x (by `rm(x)`) if you don't need it.

Note that this will be easier if you have to replace a lot of for loops!

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can access columns in `lapply()`. Just like below:

```
lapply(1, function(i, df) { y$col}, df=yourdf)[[1]]
```

Here in `lapply()`, just pass `yourdf` as an additional parameter and then you are able to reference columns using `df$any_column_you_want` inside the function.